# neo4j batch import issues while importing

Tags: neo4j

There is a problem when I am trying to import 2 example csv files that is in sample folder at https://github.com/jexp/batch-import. I have uploaded the snapshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/geyma.jpg. Any suggestion?

Comment: it is saying index users not configured, can you post indexing related code.

Comment: Thank you ramesh for the feedback. I have changed the properties as Mr.Max suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramesh is right, open up your batch.properties file and add (for example):

```
batch_import.node_index.users=exact
```

Comment: That started working Mr.Max. I have two csv file, one with nodes and one with relationships. The nodes csv file is geting imported succesfully where as the relationship csv file cannot be imported and its showing an error. Please click here http://imgur.com/1DJi6Pd.
Incase you wondering about the csv file, then it has data with comma separated. I have put a snapshot here http://imgur.com/UPHp0Ch. Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: it's complaining that it can't find node 10k, so make sure that is in the nodes.csv

Comment: node 10k is in nodes .csv. You can have a look here http://imgur.com/dx9sfsR

Comment: Weird... try adding this to your batch.properties file:

batch_import.mapdb_cache.disable=true